# adding social login to exising JHipster app

Tags: jhipster

I've been developing a JHipster app for a number of days and I realize now that it was initially created without the ***Social login*** option.  What is the best approach for adding it after the fact?  Can I simply add     ***"enableSocialSignIn": true*** to *.yo-rc.json* and re-run ***yo jhipster*** (everything is checked into git), or are the changes too significant?

Comment: I have used this approach when I move my app from monolith to microservices and it worked good. Just be sure that you have all relevant files into git. YMHO I think that is also good to have the save code formatting as the code which is generated from JHipster. In that way u can have a better overview of the changes when you are generating with other settings, e.g. enableSocialSignIn:true or when you are making an upgrade!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than clobber my app, I ended up creating a new temporary JHipster app, doing a diff of the two apps, and selectively copying over only the code that pertained to social logic (and eliminating the code that pertained to OAuth2, since I also switched to session based / spring security authentication as well).